# Matlab working with Matrices / images to reset a certain pixel(3 dims)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to decide, for a single frame, whether I want to add it to the frame or not..
(Implementing background subtraction)..

How do I do it in a fast way? ( I did it with looping and it's working realll slow...)

This is what I have: (seq is input, diff is the image I am testing against, and F is the new image)

```
  for y = 1:height
     for x = 1:width
        res = 0;
        for c = 1:channels
            if diff(y,x,c) > thresh
                res = 1;
            end
        end
        if res == 1
            F(y,x, :) = seq(y,x,:);
        else
            F(y,x, :) = 0;
        end
     end
  end
```

Thanks !!

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense how you are using diff, can you explain what this threshold should describe?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some definition for the filter, but apart from this I can provide a basic template for image masking:

```
img=imread(...) %some input image
mask = sum( img>threshold , 3) >0
%now the tricky part, we have a nxmx3 image and a nxm mask to filter:
img2=bsxfun(@times,img,mask);
```

You may modify the bsxfun-line, but using a binary matrix to indicate which image to select is the most common method. Thus adapt the mask to your requirements.

Comment: The `for` loop algorithm should be translated with something like `mask = sum( img>threshold , 3) >0` : if at least one of the three RGB component is > threshold, keep the pixel.

Comment: @Magla: you are probably right. I understood diff to be the build in function, but looking at the code again it seems to be a matrix containing an image.